# Mamp Pro alias to directory?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, apache

Trying to add this simple code to my httpd.conf but it gets overwritten each time I start the server

```
Alias /ws /path/to/public
<Directory /path/to/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

There are spots in mamp pro to enter stuff but I can't find any documentation on what they do.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/L9t9/content))</sub>

Help?

Comment: you can always play with it youself. httpd.conf accepts `#`-style comments. so put a couple comments into those boxes and see where they show up in the generated .conf file.

Comment: Good idea, let me try that...

Comment: Were you able to finally do it?

Answer (score 3):

The answer might be a little late... but for everyone searching

The first field "Customized virtual host directory Settings will be added to the directory section:

```
<Directory /path/to/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    #My directory options
</Directory>
```

The second field "Customized virtual host general settings" will be pasted in the virtual host section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #My virtual host options
</VirtualHost>
```

So in your case, just put everything inside the SECOND box and it will look like this with default settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-servername.dev

    DocumentRoot "/your/path/to/public"

    <Directory "/your/path/to/public">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all  
    </Directory>
    Alias /ws /path/to/public
    <Directory /path/to/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can always check what happened in the following path:

```
/Users/<YOUR-USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/httpd.conf
```